# Can I reuse conditions in nested if statements?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Is it possible to reuse a condition from a parent if statement?

**Example:**

```
if a == b || a == c
    if a == b
        #do thing
    elsif a == c
        #do the other thing
    end
    #in addition to this thing
end
```

Can the initial `a == b` or `a == c` be referenced in the nested statements without manually retyping them?

Comment: storing them into variables?

Comment: In Python there is a finally part you could put your additional part in. Only thing that comes to my mind is storing the result in a variable. Some languages allow you to assign them in an if statent like "if (c = a==b...".

Comment: What are those regexes doing?

Comment: @PericlesTheo I think the problem with storing them in variables like `z = a == b || y = a == c` is that `z` and `y` can lives outside of the scope of the if statement.

Comment: You can replace `elsif a == c` with `else`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comment in ruby, the process of storing a variable inside returns the value of the variable so you can do this:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 3

if cond1 = a == b || cond2 =  a == c then
    if cond1 then
        puts "a==b"
    elsif cond2
        puts "a==c"
    end
    puts "do this"

end
```

the result

```
irb(main):082:0> a==b
do this
=> true
i
```

Comment: I like this solution, except, of course, the condition variable names should be replaced with meaningful variable names, though we hanve no way of knowing what those names might be.

Comment: You stole my comment! At least cite me, dough.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following.

```
case a
when b
  ...
  common_code
when c
  ...
  common_code
end

def common_code
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a flag.

```
if a == b
  flag = true
  # do thing
elsif a == c
  flag = true
  # do the other thing
else
  flag = false
end
if flag
  # in addition to this thing
end
```

or

```
flag =
case a
when b
  # do thing
  true
when c
  # do the other thing
  true
else
  false
end
if flag
  # in addition to this thing
end
```

Comment: Readers: remember, beauty is in the eye of the beholder. I might like this better if it were [June 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_Day_(United_States)).